# Formula to cut the strings from a field

Tags: apex, formula, validation, custom

I have a field where the name will be stored as "Account A acquired Account B". 
Now from this field, I need the word to be split in two parts for two different field. one is **before acquired** and one is **after acquired**. It will be like `field 1: Account A, field 2: Account B`

I used the following formulas but it isn't giving me correct output.

```
field 1 formula:  IF(CONTAINS(Name, "acquired"), LEFT(Name,Find("acquired", Name)-1), '')

field 2 formula: IF(CONTAINS(Name, "acquired"), RIGHT(Name,Find("acquired", Name)), '')
```

Can anyone please suggest changes in the above formulaes

Comment: Can you add the erroneous output you're getting?

Comment: If the name is like ABC Corp acquired DEF Corp, I'm getting the output as ABC Cor for one field and red DEF Corp for second field. The account name lengths might vary but I need the string to be cut before and after acquired word in the sentence. Using the given formulae, I cannot able to predict the proper outcome

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to do. I cannot understand what error you’re encountering. Please update your question m

Comment: @SebastianKessel, Its not error but I need a correct formula where I can exactly divide the string before and after "acquired" word in the name field irrespective of field length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your first formula is cutting off the last character of the firm name - it works for me. In fact, you should subtract 2 from the `FIND()` result to remove the trailing space (but using `-1` will display fine, just with a space after the name):

```
IF(CONTAINS(Name, "acquired"), 
    LEFT(Name,Find("acquired", Name)-2), 
    '')
```

For the second formula, you need to account both for the overall length of the string, and the fact that `FIND(Name,"acquired")` returns the position of the "a" in "acquired":

```
IF(CONTAINS(Name, "acquired"), 
    RIGHT(Name,LEN(Name)-Find("acquired", Name)-8), 
    '')
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, it worked :)